# has_many through association | NameError: uninitialized constant Organization::Organizationsuser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have two models joined with a has_many through association:

Here are the tables:

```
  create_table "organizations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "mission"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "organizations_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "organization_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
  end
```

Here are the models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :organizationsusers
  has_many :organizations, :through => :organizationsusers

end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizationsusers
  has_many :users, :through => :organizationsusers
  has_many :categories, as: :categorizable

end

class OrganizationsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

When I create a new organization via my form it creates adequately. However I keep getting:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Organization::Organizationsuser
```

If I do something like this for example:

```
o = Organization.last

  Organization Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  ORDER BY "organizations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Organization id: 1, name: "HOU", description: "fkjndskj", mission: "fnskjdfs", created_at: "2015-09-16 07:35:42", updated_at: "2015-09-16 07:35:42">

o.users
NameError: uninitialized constant Organization::Organizationsuser
```

Why is this happening? Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NameError: uninitialized constant Organization::Organizationsuser

Changing `organizationsusers` to `organizations_users` in your code should fix the error.

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :organizations_users
  has_many :organizations, :through => :organizations_users
end

#organization.rb
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations_users
  has_many :users, :through => :organizations_users
  has_many :categories, as: :categorizable
end
```

Comment: thanks! this got ```o.users``` to not throw error. But the query set is empty for any organization I create for some reason. Do I have to pass a user_id as a param? I am even allowing all strong parameters with    ```def organization_params params.require(:organization).permit! end``` but no luck

Comment: @james Can you post the query that is generated when you give `o.users`?

Comment: ```o.users
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "organizations_users" ON "users"."id" = "organizations_users"."user_id" WHERE "organizations_users"."organization_id" = $1  [["organization_id", 5]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>```

Answer (score 0):

I have read you code. You have typo to write your associations.
Please change `:organizationsusers` into `:organizations_users`. I hope this help you

Comment: Thanks! This got ```o.users``` to not throw error. But the query set is empty for any organization I create for some reason. Do I have to pass a user_id as a param? I am even allowing all strong parameters with ```def organization_params params.require(:organization).permit! end``` but no luck